# WPF: access controls from usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a usercontrol whit a RichTextBox control and a TreeView, and I want to bind a commands like Copy, Cut, Paste etc which are in Window not in usercontrol but I dont know how to access  Elements from usercontrol? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a namespace to your XAML file and add your usercontrol with the given namespace prefix

as such:

xlmns:myuserctrl = "assemblyreference here"

Make sure you give your usercontrol a name which you can access in your code-behind.

You should then be able to access your controls from that variable inside your code-behind. If not, create some properties in the usercontrol class referencing the controls inside the user control.

Answer (score 0):

There's no straightforward way of accessing child elements of user controls in XAML. However you can get creative and implement a custom type descriptor that exposes control fields as properties, which you can then bind to from the elements outside of the user control.